# Integral in Edwards' book

Tags: limits, logarithms, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

I would like to understand the proof that
$$\lim_{\tau\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \int_{a-iT}^{a+iT}\frac{\log(1-s/(\sigma+i\tau))}{s^2}x^s ds =0$$
where $a$ and $\sigma$ are real numbers with $a>\sigma$. This is a step from Edwards' book "The Riemann zeta function" on page 29 (1974 edition) in the proof of the principal term for the analytic formula for $\pi(x)$ that is the main result in Riemann's 1859 paper. The book just states "it is not difficult to prove..." and mentions the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, but I am having trouble putting a bound on the integrand because of the complex logarithm.

Comment: $\frac{\log(1-s/(\sigma+i\tau))}{s^2} x^s \to 0$ in $L^1(\Re(s)=a)$

Comment: @reuns Isn't that just restating the question? I was wondering how to prove that $\frac{\log(1-s/(\sigma+i\tau))}{s^2}x^s\rightarrow 0$ in $L^1(\Re(s)=a)$.

Comment: You can say that the $L^1$ norm is $O(\int_{\Re(s)=a,|\Im(s)| > \tau^{1/2}} \frac{1+\log|s|}{|s^2|} x^\sigma d|s|+
\int_{\Re(s)=a,|\Im(s)| < \tau^{1/2}} \frac{1/\tau^{1/2}}{|s^2|} x^\sigma d|s|)
$

Comment: How do I see that $|\log(1-s/(\sigma+i\tau))|\leq 1+\log(|s|)$ when $|\Im(s)|>\tau^{1/2}$?

Comment: The argument stays in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and the absolute value is bounded by $1+|s|$